# Git Show - how to avoid .../ omissions

Tags: git

In Git show I am getting a lot of contractions or .../ "abbreviations" - see the example below. I am unable to resolve these back to the full path, is there a way to have git-show provide the full path for every alteration in the commit?

So far I have been using the below since I don't want the full detail of all the code changed.

```
git show --pretty=oneline --stat f760478a5788d2e8e6b0f7be793b015a9e2c043e
```

Example output where I cannot resolve the full path.

```
 ../src/MyApp.Deployment.Util/packages.config   |     9 +
 .../src/MyApp.Deployment.sln                    |    65 +
 .../MyApp.DeploymentServer/src/Readme.txt       |    94 +
 .../x-build/cdeploy.nuspec                        |    14 +
 .../PowerApplication.MyDll.Engine.dll     |   Bin 0 -> 372736 bytes
 ...ation.MyDll.Engine.resources (104).dll |   Bin 0 -> 16384 bytes
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit-show%5D+stat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the filepath is too long, longer than the default value, it displays `...` instead of the fullpath. You can add numbers after [--stat](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show#Documentation/git-show.txt---statltwidthgtltname-widthgtltcountgt) to specify how much space each line can use to display the filename and other info. `--stat=999` should work in almost all cases. You can find more details in the manual.

`--stat[=<width>[,<name-width>[,<count>]]]`

> Generate a diffstat. By default, as much space as necessary will be
> used for the filename part, and the rest for the graph part. Maximum
> width defaults to terminal width, or 80 columns if not connected to a
> terminal, and can be overridden by <width>. The width of the filename
> part can be limited by giving another width <name-width> after a
> comma. The width of the graph part can be limited by using
> --stat-graph-width=<width> (affects all commands generating a stat graph) or by setting diff.statGraphWidth=<width> (does not affect git
> format-patch). By giving a third parameter <count>, you can limit the
> output to the first <count> lines, followed by ... if there are more.
>
> These parameters can also be set individually with
> --stat-width=<width>, --stat-name-width=<name-width> and --stat-count=<count>.

Comment: That works great. Is there a value for "unlimited" as opposed to trying to set some arbitrary value greater than what you think the max is?

Comment: @MurrayFoxcroft I don't find such a value or an option to cancel the limit. Maybe `--numstat` is better than `--stat` or `--stat=999` in your case. Besieds, `--numstat` is more friendly for script parsing.